# jstree dnd and how to limit drops

Tags: drag-and-drop, jstree

I have a jstree as follows:

- Cities

  - London

    - Paul
    - Jack
  - New York

    - Lisa
    - Fred

So I want to drag and drop the Peoples from one city to another,
but not people to people.
Please can anyone show o code piece for that solution.
I am able to drop at people to cities and also people to people,
but people to people makes no sense in that case.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: This question may have a answer to your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23226768/jstree-prevent-moving-node-into-child-nodes

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by using dynatree:

```
onDragEnter: function(node, sourceNode) {
    if (node.data.isFolder)
        return ["over"];
    else
        return ["before", "after"];
},
```

That is exact what I need